# Group by date and item and count rows for export to chart

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot, group-by

I need some help to solve a problem that's far beyond my poor skills.

I have a table where I register the access at each products datasheet, therefore for each access I have a record with `ItemCode (SKU)`, `TimeStamp` and some other info like this:

```
|SKU|TimeStamp |Country|Referral|
|AT1|1410290655|Spain  |http... |
|AT2|1410290428|Spain  |http... |
|AT2|1410290215|Spain  |http... |
......
|AT1|1410282324|Spain  |http... |
|AT3|1410282255|Spain  |http... |
|AT5|1410282128|Spain  |http... |
|AT2|1410282015|Spain  |http... |
```

I need to draw a Line Chart with all these info and I need to show for each day
of the month how many times each item (`AT1`, `AT2`, `AT3`.....) has been shown
but since I will choose the TimeFrame, the list of Items (`AT1`, `AT2`, `AT3`, `AT4`...) is not fixed but has to be dynamically generated by the query..

Since I'll be using Google Charts, I would need an array like this:

```
['Date', 'AT1', 'AT2', 'AT3', 'AT4', 'AT5',....]
['141029', 125,  312,   512,   371,   125,.....]
['141028', 143,  213,   252,   621,   246,.....]
['141027', 215,  412,   312,   571,   425,.....]
```

Can anyone give me some hints to reach such target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic pivot is what you want. This code won't give you the exact output you're looking for but it should serve as a hint and something to work from. It should be easy enough for you to export the data to CSV file with headers for use with Google Charts.

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols= ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(sku) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sku FROM wLogs) AS Columns

SET @sql =
  N'SELECT CAST(date AS char(6)) date, ' + @cols + ' 
    FROM (SELECT sku, LEFT([TimeStamp],6) date FROM wLogs) a
    PIVOT (COUNT([sku])
          FOR sku IN (' + @cols + ')) AS p
        ORDER BY date DESC'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
date   AT1         AT2         AT3         AT5
------ ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
141028 1           1           1           1
141029 1           2           0           0
```

Comment: @user3304110 Oh, I assumed the timestamp was in a date format, I've changed the query now, please try it again. Also, you might want to remove your answer as it seems to be meant as a comment on my answer.

Comment: Hi!

Thanks again for answering..
actually I tried to add a comment instead of an answer but could not be so long.

Now Works (removed second ")" from "Left([TimeStamp],6))"

Really thanks!

Sergio

Comment: @user3304110 Happy it works and sorry for sloppy editing by me leaving the surplus`)`

Comment: Do not worry! you left also some work for me :-)
have been able also to order the results by SKU ASC.. 
but...Query is little more complex.. should also filter results by Date and by SellerID and join with other table for a test

I added
DECLARE @sellerID AS NVARCHAR(20)
SET @sellerID='seller1'

and changed
FROM (SELECT sku, LEFT([TS],10) date FROM wLogs) a
into
FROM (SELECT sku, LEFT([TS],10) date FROM wLogs where sellerID='+@sellerID+') a

But I get 
Invalid Column name 'seller1'

Clearly do not want you make all the dirty work.. but pls suggest me the path to follow to learn how handle it

Comment: @user3304110 You need to use triple quotes so that the `@sellerID`gets quoted inside the `@sql`string. Try it like this `FROM wLogs where sellerid = ''' + @sellerID + ''') a`